HikariCP OracleDB PoolEntry, Clob objects Flush
I am using HikariCP and Oracle DB, in the HikariCP PoolEntry, T4CConnection has T4C8TTIClob objects cached in heap memory, how can we configure in Spring boot application to avoid caching or flushing the cached input Clob object. Have already used "oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize" to 0 still the PoolEntry Clob objects are taking huge heap memory. Request your guidance on how to resolve this issue
Have already used "oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize" to 0 still the PoolEntry Clob objects are taking huge heap memory.
Expecting the PoolEntry Clob objects to be flushed and not store clob objects in heap memory
